# For reheating stuffing in the oven, how long would you bake it and at what temperature?

Tags: baking, reheating, stuffing, thanksgiving

I've made [Bread Stuffing with Fresh Herbs from Cooks Illustrated](http://www.cooksillustrated.com/recipes/detail.asp?docid=26408) this year for Thanksgiving, and I'm going to need to reheat it to serve. It cooked for seventy minutes at 375 the first time around, but I'm not sure how hot to set the oven or for how long to give it to get it hot without drying it out terribly the second time. Also, is there a standard amount of chicken broth people add to stuffing on reheating?

Comment: I'm also going to assume that it's been in the fridge before being reheated, and it's going into the oven with or just after the turkey (ie, the oven's preheated) ... I'd take the stuffing out 20-30min before you plan to bake it, so the dish doesn't go straight from fridge to hot oven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd reheat it at 375 again, covered, and add maybe 1/2 cup liquid to start. It will probably take about 30-40 minutes to come back to temperature. If you have an instant-read thermometer, it is at a servable temperature at 160, though you may want to go a fair amount higher if it will sit long before being eaten.